# How can I force xenserver to create a full (not paravirtualized) vm?

Tags: xenserver, paravirtualization, hvm

Exact opposite of this question:

[How to makesure VM is in Para virtualization mode on XEN?](https://serverfault.com/questions/430231/how-to-makesure-vm-is-in-para-virtualization-mode-on-xen)

I've got xenserver 6.2 and nowhere in the UI when creating a VM does it give me the option to use HVM and not paravirtualize by default.

Any ideas?

Comment: One question - why to do that? If your OS is supported for PVM virtualization, it's better to go with it - you will get better performance, text console, simple and reliable EFI-like booting with *pygrub*...

Comment: The answer is "because I am building software and I need to be able to test it on many platforms that my users will be using." Now my question to you is: Why are there so many people who would rather tell you what you're doing is wrong, rather than try and answer your question?

Comment: Because your question doesn't reveal that you have this knowledge and my experience tells many ppl try to solve the problem without really understanding consequences, so I try different options (don't get offended - this is purely hypothetical). And well, before posting the comment I've already posted the answer, so the "rather" word is missed. :-)

Comment: Fair enough. I concede. That's a reasonable explanation. Thanks.

Comment: Apologies, I jumped the gun. But soooo many times in my life, when I ask for help I run into the problem of people who want to help me their way instead of trying to help me my way. And I understand that there are situations where I need somebody to point out a solution outside the box I'm thinking in, and since as you point out, I did not make that clear, your comment is not unreasonable.

Answer (score 1):

Virtualization type is defined in a template every new VM is based on.

There's a template named *Other install media* which provisions a newly created VM to be HVM-type.